# Following tests fails when .deleteAll() method executed before it

Tags: java, spring, junit

I've a JUnit tests that checks if the service is working correctly. After each tests or before each I would like to clean up the database table, so I execute `repository.deleteAll();` but then test is failing. Without it the test works fine, but it takes the `row` from previous test. When I did the deleteAll() in the void test method that fails it was failing but when I added `synchronized(this) { repository.deleteAll();}` test was green. What might be wrong here any ideas? Also weird is that when I do not execute the deleteAll() and run all tests everything is green but it should not be, because at the last test I am checking the quantity of products. If the product name was in the database take his quantity.

```
public class ShoppingCartServiceTest extends DatabaseConnectionTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceImpl productService;

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingCartService shoppingCartService;


        @Before
        public void setUp() {
               productRepository.deleteAll();
        }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddProduct() {
        Product product = new Product(1L,"Blue Jeans", "Trend Blue Jeans",
                ProductCategory.CLOTHES, 5, 30.00);
        shoppingCartService.addProduct(product);
        assertNotNull(productService.findById(product.getId()));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldIncreaseEntityOfProductWhenAlreadyExists() {
        Product product = new Product(1L, "White Shorts", "Extra White Shorts",
                ProductCategory.CLOTHES, 3, 15.00);
        shoppingCartService.addProduct(product);
        Product productTwo = new Product(2L, "White Shorts", "Extra White Shorts",
                ProductCategory.CLOTHES, 5, 15.00);
        shoppingCartService.addProduct(productTwo);
        assertNotNull(productService.findById(product.getId()));
        assertNull(productService.findById(productTwo.getId()));
        Integer expectedQuantity = product.getQuantity() + productTwo.getQuantity();
        assertEquals(expectedQuantity, productService.findById(product.getId()).getQuantity());
    }
}
```

```
    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        if (product == null)
            return;

        // if the product is already added, then increase the quantity
        // if not the add it as new product
        Product actualProduct = productRepository.findByName(product.getName());
        if (actualProduct != null) {
            int quantity = product.getQuantity() + actualProduct.getQuantity();
            actualProduct.setQuantity(quantity);
            productRepository.save(actualProduct);
        }
        else {
            productRepository.save(product);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @KamilW That the product with id 1 is null, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Try to call `saveAndFlush()` instead of `save()`